# If span is next to link Jquery

Tags: jquery

I've this code :

```
<span class="span_inbox">1</span>
<a href="#" class="link_message">Message</a>
```

If My span is next to my link, I want my link to add the class "link_message".
So I write this code :

```
if($('.link_message').closest('.span_inbox') {
  $(this).addClass('test');
}
```

But it does not work. Thanks for your help !

Comment: [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/): For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing **the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors** in the DOM tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try .next() in situations like this, to target the next element matching the matching value:

```
$('.span_inbox').next('a').addClass('link_message');
```

Comment: I'm assuming the 'a' tag does not yet have class '.link_message' as he seems to want to add that class.

Comment: Or without `.next()` -> `$(".span_inbox + a").addClass("test")`